# Не работает Input в C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

Делаю игру на Unity. В скрипте C# хочу написать такую строку кода, но Visual Studio почему-то не видит Input и GetAxis, хотя разработка игр с помощью Unity у меня в Visual Studio установленна. Подскажите, что делать?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }
}
```

Comment: М.б. нужные неймспейсы не подключены

Comment: `using UnityEngine;`

Comment: @aepot using UnityEngine прописанно

Comment: Если присутсвует `using UnityEngine` то можете подсказать что имеете в виду под "VS не видит"

Comment: @Alemkhan Utepkaliev не подсвечивает, и не предлагает при написании

Comment: VS или VS Code? Какой версии?